Unsorted Intersection
a = {0, 3, 1, 2, 3};
b = {5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7};
c = {3, 1, 8, 5};


UnsortedIntersection[lists__?VectorQ] :=
 Fold[
  DeleteDuplicates @ DeleteElements[Join[##], Join @@ UniqueElements[{##}]] &,
  {lists}]

The sort order of the intersecting elements should follow their appearance in the first list, here a:
Wanted:
UnsortedIntersection[a, b, c]


{3, 1}

Not wanted:
Intersection[a, b, c]


{1, 3}

Some other examples:
UnsortedIntersection[a, b]


{3, 1, 2}

UnsortedIntersection[b, c]


{5, 1, 3}

UnsortedIntersection[a, {-1}]


{}

Question
My solution seems to function, but uses DeleteElements and UniqueElements. These two
functions are rather slow and were only introduced in V 13.1.
How could a faster and/or simpler functional solution look like?

Updated with faster code:
Clear[FastestInTheWest]
FastestInTheWest[x__?VectorQ] := 
 Cases[DeleteDuplicates@First[{x}], Alternatives @@ Intersection[x]]

Compared with Ben Izd's code:
SeedRandom[1234];
{a, b, c} = RandomInteger[{0, 9999}, {3, 10000}];

res1 = NewUnsortedIntersection[a, b, c]; // AbsoluteTiming

res2 = FastestInTheWest[a, b, c]; // AbsoluteTiming

res1 === res2


{0.0168548, Null}

{0.0025741, Null}

True

Old code:
UnsortedIntersection[lists__?VectorQ] := 
 SortBy[Intersection[lists], FirstPosition[First@{lists}, #] &]

UnsortedIntersection[a, b, c]
UnsortedIntersection[a, b]
UnsortedIntersection[b, c]
UnsortedIntersection[a, {-1}]


{3, 1}

{3, 1, 2}

{5, 1, 3}

{}


Since we have the elements using the Intersection function, the only thing we have to do is to reorder them, here is how we can do that efficiently using SortBy:
ClearAll[NewUnsortedIntersection];

NewUnsortedIntersection[list1_, others__] := 
 SortBy[Intersection[list1, others], First@*PositionIndex[list1]]

The key here is the PositionIndex which gives us the element's position (since it returns a list, First@* was used). The SortBy sorts by ascending order, and returning the position of the first appearance of the element will give us the desired result.

PositionIndex was introduced in Version 10 (2014)

Benchmarking
SeedRandom[1234];
{a, b, c} = RandomInteger[{0, 9999}, {3, 10000}];

res0 = UnsortedIntersection[a, b, c]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Output: {3.02529, Null} *)

res1 = azerbajdzan`UnsortedIntersection[a, b, c]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Output: {1.51155, Null} *)

res2 = NewUnsortedIntersection[a, b, c]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Output: {0.0235903, Null} *)



res0 === res1 === res2
(* Output: True *)

On my computer, on 10,000 elements between 0 and 9,999 it's around 100 times faster.

Using:
a = {0, 3, 1, 2, 3};
b = {5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7};
c = {3, 1, 8, 5};

You can use KeyIntersection, e.g.
fun[u_,v_]:=Module[{s=Association[Thread[#->1]]&/@{u,v}}, Keys[KeyIntersection[s]][[1]]]

Testing:
Column[HoldForm[Intersection[#1, #2]] -> fun[#1, #2] & @@@ 
  Join @@ (Permutations /@ Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2}])]



I think you forgot to include your fun :)

Sorry you are right. Will correct when I get a chance
